# How to check if an arraylist already contains an object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm trying to get my shopping cart to recognise if an item has already been added to the cart and then update the quantity to be one more however it just keeps having the statement as false.

Here is my page load handler where it creates a new product from details sent in the query string.

```
Private Sub ShoppingCartPage_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (IsPostBack) Then
        If Not (Request.QueryString.ToString().Length.Equals(0)) Then
            Dim newProduct As Product = New Product(Request.QueryString("ProductCode"), Request.QueryString("ProductName"), Request.QueryString("Category"), Val(Request.QueryString("Price")), Request.QueryString("Description"))

            If Session("shoppingCartSession") Is Nothing Then
                shoppingCart = New ArrayList()
                shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
                Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
            ElseIf (shoppingCart.Contains(newProduct.itemID)) Then
                For Each item As Product In shoppingCart
                    If item.Equals(Request.QueryString("ProductCode")) Then
                        item.updateQuantity()
                    End If
                Next

            Else
                shoppingCart = CType(Session("shoppingCartSession"), ArrayList)
                shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
                Session.Add("shoppingCartSession", shoppingCart)
            End If
        End If
        shoppingCart = CType(Session("shoppingCartSession"), ArrayList)
        createShoppingCartTable()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use an `ArrayList`. It is basically obsolete these days. Use a strongly typed [**`List(Of T)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead, or if you want to provide lookup through the item ID, use a [**`Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.  Firstly, if you're adding to your `ArrayList` like this:

```
shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
```

then you are adding `Product` objects.  In that case, why would you expect this to be useful:

```
If (shoppingCart.Contains(newProduct.itemID)) Then
```

`newProduct.itemID` is presumably an `Integer` or the like so of course the collection doesn't contain it.  It doesn't contain any `Integer` values because it contains `Product` objects.  You need to check whether it contains a `Product` object with that `itemID`, not whether it contains that `itemID` directly.  I would replace all this:

```
If Session("shoppingCartSession") Is Nothing Then
    shoppingCart = New ArrayList()
    shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
    Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
ElseIf (shoppingCart.Contains(newProduct.itemID)) Then
    For Each item As Product In shoppingCart
        If item.Equals(Request.QueryString("ProductCode")) Then
            item.updateQuantity()
        End If
    Next

Else
    shoppingCart = CType(Session("shoppingCartSession"), ArrayList)
    shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
    Session.Add("shoppingCartSession", shoppingCart)
End If
```

with this:

```
shoppingCart = TryCast(Session("shoppingCartSession"), ArrayList)

If shoppingCart Is Nothing Then
    shoppingCart = New ArrayList
    Session("shoppingCartSession") = shoppingCart
End If

Dim existingProduct = shoppingCart.Cast(Of Product)().
                                   SingleOrDefault(Function(p) p.itemID = newProduct.itemID)

If existingProduct Is Nothing Then
    shoppingCart.Add(newProduct)
Else
    existingProduct.updateQualtity()
End If
```

That said, I would also be following the suggestion by @VisualVincent and using a `List(Of Product)` rather than an `ArrayList`.  If you do that then you can omit the `Cast` call in my suggested code.